# Allow my own class in Rails to be configured with block syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, configuration

I often see code of the form

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include ApiHelper

  # ## Mock Framework
  #
  # If you prefer to use mocha, flexmock or RR, uncomment the appropriate line:
  #
  # config.mock_with :mocha
  # config.mock_with :flexmock
  # config.mock_with :rr

  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  # If true, the base class of anonymous controllers will be inferred
  # automatically. This will be the default behavior in future versions of
  # rspec-rails.
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false

  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods

end
```

Is there a feature in Rails that lets me do something similar? I want to be able to configure my own library with a similar syntax within config/initializers/my_class.rb

```
MyClass.configure do |config|
  # allow configuration here
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't know if rails provides a helper for that, but i wrote my own tiny solution for this problem that i use in several gems: https://github.com/phoet/confiture

it let's you define configurations:

```
module Your
  class Configuration
    include Confiture::Configuration

    confiture_allowed_keys(:secret, :key)
    confiture_defaults(secret: 'SECRET_STUFF', key: 'EVEN_MOAR_SECRET')
  end
end
```

and have an easy api to do the configuration:

```
Your::Configuration.configure do |config|
  config.secret = 'your-secret'
  config.key    = 'your-key'
end
```

besides this, there are a lot of other config tools out there like configatron or simpleconfig.

Comment: Looks awesome. I will give it a try and report back. Something like this should be included in rails IMO...

Answer (score 2):

Nothing special is needed in Rails - it is simple Ruby code. Here is how it can be done:

```
class MyClass
  def self.configure(&block)
    a_hash = { :car => "Red" }
    puts "Hello"
    yield a_hash
    puts "There"
  end    
end


MyClass.configure do |config|
  puts "In Block"
  puts config[:car]
end
```

Output:

```
Hello
In Block
Red
There
```

I am yielding a hash, but you can yield whatever object you want to.

Answer (score 2):

Rails will load all the Ruby files in the `config/initializers` directory when starting up the server.

If you want to use the same style for your own custom configurable class then you just have to implement a `configure` class method that accepts a block and passes a configuration object to that block. e.g.

```
class MyClassConfiguration
  # configuration attributes
end

class MyClass
  def self.configure
    yield configuration if block_given?
  end

  def self.configuration
    @config ||= MyClassConfiguration.new
  end
end
```

Using phoet's gem would be even easier.

Its worth taking a look at how RSpec does it if you are curious:

The `RSpec.configure` method is in https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/master/lib/rspec/core.rb

The `Configuration` class is implemented in https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/master/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb

Answer (score 1):

A global configuration set via the block.

```
module VkRobioAPI
  module Configuration

  OPTION_NAMES = [
      :client_id,
      :redirect_uri,
      :display,
      :response_type
    ]

    attr_accessor *OPTION_NAMES

    def configure 
      yield self if block_given?
      self
    end

  end
end


module VkRobioAPI
  extend VkRobioAPI::Configuration

  class << self
    def result
     puts VkRobioAPI.client_id 
    end
  end
end
```

Example:

```
  VkRobioAPI.configure do |config|
    config.client_id       = '3427211'
    config.redirect_uri   = 'bEWLUZrNLxff1oQpEa6M'
    config.response_type = 'http://localhost:3000/oauth/callback'
    config.display = 'token'
  end
```

Result:

```
VkRobioAPI.result
    #3427211
    #=> nil
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using rails, you can just include `ActiveSupport::Configurable` into your class and off you go. Outside of rails, you will have to add the `activesuport` gem to your Gemfile or gemspec and then call `require 'active_support/configurable'`.

**Example**

```
class MyClass
  include ActiveSupport::Configurable
end
```

**Usage**

*With block*

```
MyClass.configure do |config|
  config.key = "something"
  config.key2 = "something else"
end
```

*or inline, without block*

```
MyClass.config.key = "something"
MyClass.config.key2 = "something else"
```

*or like a hash*

```
MyClass.config[:key] = "somehting"
MyClass.config[:key2] = "something else"
```

**Note:** key can be any character of your choice.